# read a .dat file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am unable to read '.dat' file. I have tired all the possible ways and tired googling it but I could not find the solution. All it gives me is a null value for integer and a junk value for a string variable or char. This what I have written

```
ifstream file;
file.open("data1.dat"); // I have also tried this way too like file.open("data1.dat", ios::binary, ios::in);
int data=0;
file >> data;
cout << data << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

I am using visual studio to compile this code. I am pretty sure that the pointer is entering into the data file but I don't know for what reason the data is not being read.

The .dat file consists of integer number per line ranging from 0, so I just need to read the file and get number from each line and should find the sum of all numbers in the file. The file contains number like
5,
468,
3200, 
32, etc.,. Each number is in a new line. The file can contain any number of records. [this how .dat file looks when opened using a notepad editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAvXs.png)

Comment: you need to provide a few lines of data1.dat

Comment: File formats are not defined by extensions and, to add insult to injury, the extension `.dat` is used as a catch-all for generally arbitrary custom binary formats. We have _no idea_ how to parse your file, because we have _no idea_ what it's made of. You would have to provide its specification, though I suspect that if you were to merely read it yourself you'd probably be most of the way towards solving the problem.

Comment: `.dat` is no standard file format like xml, it just means "data" - a common type for any kind of data, and of binary. Without knowing how the file was created, there is no (easy) way to find out how to read it

Comment: I will say that it's extremely unlikely you can use the formatted extraction operators for this task; those are designed to read "text files" where numbers and strings are encoded in a human-readable format. `.dat` does not imply this.

Comment: the file consists of numbers and one number per line, the number can be 0 or any big number, all I have to do is read the file and give the sum of all numbers. I should not use arrays to store the data. It is a linked lists concept.

Comment: That is not sufficiently precise. You would need to provide a precise specification.

Comment: Open it in a text editor and paste what you get here. If a simple editor like Notepad can read it as you described it, it should work - however if it gives you garbage, chances are you're not handling the format of the file correctly and it will need to be opened as a binary file.

Comment: From the image, I don't believe that the file contains numbers. I guess the file might had something strange in the beginning, causing it to be unreadable.

Comment: @SCaffrey: I said _the formatted extraction operators_. Binary parsing requires `.read`, not `>>`.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet   ok. yes you are right. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah. I used .read and I got the solution.

Comment: @venkateshgadde  for the benefit of others, you could add your solution as an answer.

Comment: You need to call the read function in fstream. file.read()

Answer (score 2):

Your code "works" on my system.

The following compiles (without "using namespace std;")
I changed the file name for my convenience.
I created the 't391.dat' file in the same working directory of the code, and put in 10 lines, with 1 value per line, 1..9,0.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int t391a(void)
{
   std::ifstream file;
   file.open("t391.dat"); 
   int data=0;
   file >> data;
   std::cout << data << std::endl;  // echo of input / proof it works
   //system("pause");
   file.close();
   return 0;
}
```

This code outputs the first value (which is all it attempts to do), so it is working!

The echo of input is good idea.

As an experiment, I temporarily renamed the 't391.dat' file to something else.  The code ran to completion and printed a single 0, which is *not* the first value in the file.  Perhaps this suggests your file is not being found, I won't guess.  To confirm, I restored the file, and the above 'works' again.

Missing items in your code:

- error check - file.open()
- a loop to read to end of file
- error check - formatted extract (i.e. read from stream) of data item
- file.close  - possibly not needed

If you are still working this issue, I have a minimally extended version of your code that addresses these issues.  Let me know.

Comment: My system:  Ubuntu 15.10(64), g++ v5.2.1, on older Dell hw.  note: 'system("pause")' not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ValueGet {
public:
   int data;
   ValueGet() {
   data = 0;
   }
};
int main()
{
    ValueGet vg;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("data1.dat", fstream::binary | fstream::out); // Opens a file in binary mode for input operations i.e., getting data from file.
    if (!file)
        cout << "File Not Found." << endl;
    else {
        file.seekg(0); // To make sure that the data is read from the starting position of the file.
        while (file.read((char *)&vg, sizeof(vg))) // Iterates through the file till the pointer reads the last line of the file.
            cout<<vg.data<<endl;
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[output of the data in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gudqd.png)

Comment: you have a mistake in the fstream mode used for opening the file.

Comment: Also, the part where you convert a ValueGet pointer to char * doesn't make sense. Why don't you read it into an array?

Comment: I said the code worked for me and how can you say that I have a mistake in fstream and this is part of my assignment. So I was asked not to use arrays

Comment: You're using `fstream::out`, but you say it "Opens a file in binary mode for input". Do you think these are consistent?

Comment: Oh that one I don't know for what reason when I tried fstream::in it didn't work so I tried fstream::out and it worked. Conceptually yes fstream::out is wrong in this scenario.

Comment: and if it didn't work, you should say what the error is and try to find out the root cause rather than randomly use something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way which I just found

```
     #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        unsigned int a;
        unsigned char c;
        ifstream file;
        file.open("ou.bin", ios::binary);
        if(!file.is_open()){
            cout<<"error";
            return 0;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            file>>c;
            a = c;
            a = a<<8;
            file>>c;
            a = a+ c;
            cout<<a<<endl;
        }
        file.close();
        return 0;
   }
```

This for storing two bytes in a number you can store as many bytes in a number or even one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

You will not be able to read .dat files and understand them in your context-- they are general formats used for storing data. Unless you know the contents of it or how they are specified, you will always get junk.

Comment: _"You will not be able to read .dat files"_ Were that true, such files would not exist. _"They are general formats"_ Not at all. _"Unless you know the contents"_ Yes, that's a problem with the question. _"You will always get junk"_ The so-called "junk" comes from reading uninitialised variables, because the OP is not performing any error checking on those I/O operations. This answer is not terribly helpful, I'm afraid!