# Input File format not recognized (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm writing some code for an assignment for a CS class at my university. This program is supposed to read in a `.DAT` file from the command line, assign the values in the file to an array, and then take that array and compute its average. The only issue I have is that I keep getting this error when I try to compile my code:

```
/usr/bin/ld:seven.dat: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:seven.dat:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried looking around on Google/StackOverflow a bit, but my programming knowledge is too limited to really understand what's going on, so I have no idea where my errors are. I'm compiling the program with this command:

```
g++ lab5.1.cpp seven.dat -Wall -o myprog
```

I can post some/all of the code if needed also.

Comment: The .dat file does not belong as part of the compile process.

Comment: You shouldn't put `seven.dat` in your compiler. I don't know *how* you should pass the filename to program (without seeing the code), but it definitely doesn't belong here.

Comment: Don't include seven.dat in the command line for building the application. Pass it as an argument later on to the program once it was built

Comment: Would this be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820879/read-a-dat-file-in-c

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to *compile* the `.dat` file as part of the build process when creating your `myprog` executable.  That is wrong.  Build the executable first, then pass the `.dat` file to your program when you run it, eg:

```
g++ lab5.1.cpp -Wall -o myprog
```

```
myprog seven.dat
```

Inside your code, you will receive the `seven.dat` filename in your `main()` function's `argv[]` parameter.  You can then open the `.dat` file and read its content as needed.